# Which class is called first Activity ,BroadcastReceiver or Service?

Tags: android

I have 3 classes in my App.

1. Class A extends Activity
2. class B extends BroadcastReceiver
3. Class C extends Service.

When I run the App. which one of this will be called first, I know android doesn't have a entry point.  I am blocking the incoming call in class B , and I am calling the service from activity > this service will call BroadcastReceiver > here is where I block the calls. 
When I run the code from eclipse to Droid, it is constantly blocking the call, even before I start the App. does any one know the reason. Thank you very much .

Comment: Probably because you previously setup the broadcast receiver to receive alarms from a previous run of your application. That stays in memory, and you have to remove it before you exit your application. I mean on the 2nd run the alarm is there from the 1st run. How is your BroadcastReceiver setup, both in service and in manifest?

Comment: Hello,
When I uninstall App, it is obviously not blocking calls, but when I install it until it stays in mobile it blocks calls. I have setup the BroadcastReceiver as a separate class file and calling it from Service, I have not published an implementation through the <receiver>  tag in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Service,

Another application component can start a service and it will continue to run in the background even if the user switches to another application.

So that is how you broadcast receiver is called.